# Recevied Empty array after using getItemsByColumnValue() collection method

Tags: magento2, collection, resource-model, factory, magic-getter

I'm trying to retrieve a row from a custom table named 'lmap_shipping_tablerate' using a specific value for a column postcode.

An empty array is returned when following line is used in my ResourceModel php file.

```
use MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Carrier\ResourceModel\Shipping\CollectionFactory;    
$postcode_rate_row = $this->collectionFactory->create()->getItemsByColumnValue('postcode', $value);
$this->logger->debug('Rates received: '.var_dump($postcode_rate_row));
```

Below is the directory structure

[image]
[image]

Am I using the collection factory in correct manner.

I have also created a helper file to get the desired row and used the same above code to return the array back to the calling method in ResourceModel php file but again empty array is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check other functions

```
use MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Carrier\ResourceModel\Shipping\CollectionFactory;    
$postcode_rate_row = $this->collectionFactory->create();

print_r(get_class_methods($postcode_rate_row));?>
```

It return list of methods, choose the correct one.